How does rate limiting work on Solana
using the public devnet api endpoint, this method getLatestBlockhash() is failing.
After switching my RPC, and the calls to the method working, I've determined that the most likely reason is that I am rate-limited.
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection } from "@solana/web3.js";

async function testConnection() {
    try {
        const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

        let res = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
        console.log("res", res);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

testConnection()

I would like to know

How does the rate limiting work? Does the public RPC provider block Ip Addresses?
How long does this last or is it a permanent ban?
How can I figure out if I have been rate limited. (because airdrop and program deployment are working fine)

Ref: Error: failed to get recent blockhash: TypeError: fetch failed

If you receive a 429 error from RPC, then it means you've made too many requests. A 429 response will also tell you how long to wait typically, and the RPC client will do that automatically. You can add some logging to the RPC client and log any 429s that happen.
Otherwise, the rate limits for the public endpoints are listed at https://solana.com/docs/core/clusters#solana-public-rpc-endpoints


How does the rate limiting work? Does the public RPC provider block
Ip Addresses? YES
How long does this last or is it a permanent ban? it last typically for 1 second, as it rate limited by the second.
How can I figure out if I have been rate limited. (because airdrop and
program deployment are working fine)? You can check the error code that is returned, if it equals 429, then you have been rate limited.

